# pyQt QPushButton colour

Tags: colors, pyqt, qpushbutton

Writing in Python 2.7 using pyQt 4.8.5: What is the default background colour of a pyQt QPushButton widget? I am able to set the colour green but not return it to the default colour. A snap shot of what I mean:

[image]

The function responsbile for this:

```
def StartTransmit(self):
        self.ui.Transmit.setStyleSheet("background-color: green")**
        # self.ui.Transmit.setStyleSheet("background-color: DEFAULT <later on>")
        self.number = random.randint(1,10)
        self.ui.lcd.display(self.number)
        self.timer.start(1000)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is 'light gray', example:

```
def StartTransmit(self):
    self.ui.Transmit.setStyleSheet("background-color: green")
    self.timer.start(1000)

def StopTransmit(self):
    self.ui.Transmit.setStyleSheet("background-color: light gray")
    self.timer.stop()
```

Comment: If user sets the custom colors on Windows, this solution would not work

Answer (score 1):

By default there is no styleSheet on the widgets. You can check it by just printing the styleSheet of any widget.

```
print self.pushButton.styleSheet()
```

Will print an empty string. To set the default color of a widget just set the background color to `None`

```
self.pushButton.setStyleSheet('background-color: None')
```

This way you can restore the default background color of any widget.

**Edit**

In your case, add the following code:

```
def stopTransmit(self)
    ...
    self.ui.Transmit.setStyleSheet('background-color: None')
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the widgets use the standard stylesheet of your system (Mac, Windows, GTK).

You can set a new stylesheet (to overrule the original one) using the call your are already using:

```
self.ui.Transmit.setStyleSheet('your-stylesheet')
```

If you want to revert to the original stylesheet use an empty stylesheet:

```
self.ui.Transmit.setStyleSheet('')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use something like

```
self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: color")
```

Comment: user1929959 - didn't work, just turned the button black. Of course the answer is similar to 'background-color: xxxx' - that's why I specifically asked - what's the default background color?